# Multiple database help? (django)

Tags: python, database, django

So I read over the multiple database docs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/ and it was decently helpful. I got how to show second database in setting.py and how to sync it via command prompt. but what I can't figure out is how to specify how to make a certain model get synced to/saved in a second database. especially if i haven't explicitly stated it.

Like users.

If I'm using django's users class to create users and such how can I get that saved to the second database?

Answer (score 1):

Please read the doc you provided again and carefully. The [Automatic databse routing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing) section of the doc answers your question exactly.
The routing of User DB depends on your actual usage and partition policy, there is not one sentence answer. There are examples inside the document for User, you could read and check in your local machine.

Comment: I guess I just have one question. where do I put the database routing class? in models.py?

Comment: @user1316042 it's imported by paths that defined in `DATABASE_ROUTERS`, the paths can be wherever as long as it can be found. For example you could put it inside settings.py and set `DATABASE_ROUTERS` to something like `['settings.MyRouter']`

Comment: Hmmph. I'm having problems because Users ian't defined in my models. therefor I can't give it a verbose_name that I'm using to route the models with. Right now I have all the model's verbose_name set to 'cash' but then whyen i go to try and use the router since i can't/haven't defined user I have to use `if model._meta.verbose_name != 'cash':` and when I get to allow_syncdb this runs me into some problems.

Comment: or do i need to use routing if i just specify where i want something saved/read from everytime? Will it just sync all my modelss to the second database and I just have to specify which of the two I want to use?

Comment: sorry for all the trouble. I didn't realize you can just have both exist on two databases.. hopefully they don't automatically share information.. Not sure why they would be designed to do that from the start but yeah. I think i got it.

Answer (score 1):

(Code directly from Django DOCS: [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing%29)

Routers handles in which database the data should be get or set.

If you want a router for your application (named 'myapp')

```
class MyAppRouter(object):
        """A router to control all database operations on models in
        the myapp application"""

        def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
            "Point all operations on myapp models to 'other'"
            if model._meta.app_label == 'myapp':
                return 'other'
            return None

        def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
            "Point all operations on myapp models to 'other'"
            if model._meta.app_label == 'myapp':
                return 'other'
            return None

        def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
            "Allow any relation if a model in myapp is involved"
            if obj1._meta.app_label == 'myapp' or obj2._meta.app_label == 'myapp':
                return True
            return None

        def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
            "Make sure the myapp app only appears on the 'other' db"
            if db == 'other':
                return model._meta.app_label == 'myapp'
            elif model._meta.app_label == 'myapp':
                return False
            return None
```

By adding next line to settings.py, all 'myapp' applications data will be created/saved/handled in it's own database (named "other"). All the rest of the applications uses the default database.

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['path.to.MyAppRouter']
```

The router can be saved where ever you want. Just fix the path of settings.DATABASE_ROUTERS.